# trying to remove list element with index found in another function

Tags: python, arrays, list

Using the function 
searchAccount
I found the index of a list element that I searched for using the user's input. I want to use that same index to pop the element from the list. This should be super simple but there's so much in this file now that it's hard to comprehend.

```
def deleteAccount(customerID):
#make sure the user intends to delete their account
    checkInput = str(input(("Would are you sure you would like to delete your account? Enter y for yes or n for no. ")))
    checkInput = checkInput.lower() 

    searchAccount(customerID) 

    if checkInput == "y": 
        customerlist.pop(i) 

    elif checkInput == "n":
        return 


# Search
#Look up the account information based on the customer ID.
# 
def searchAccount(yourID):


    global idLocation
    global customerlist

    with open("customers.txt", "r") as f:
        customerlist = [line.strip() for line in f]

    index = -1
    for i in range(len(customerlist)): 
        if yourID in customerlist[i]: 
           index = i
           break

    if index > -1:
        #print('Index was {}'.format(i))
        print(customerlist[i])
```

Comment: First of all your "searchAccount" should return the index or you should create an additional function which does this.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Can you share the entire program? I think there are some changes to be made, the globals and the lack of return statements are concerning,

Answer (score 1):

Removed irrelevant parts for simplicity

```
def deleteAccount(customerID):


    index = searchAccount(customerID)


    if checkInput == "y": 
        customerlist.pop(index)


def searchAccount(yourID):

    if index > -1:
        #print('Index was {}'.format(i))
        print(customerlist[i])

    return index
```

Just a heads up, I don't have the vision of your code as a whole but you might want to search for the user's account ONLY if he intends to delete it (i.e. after checking the checkInput variable).
Nonetheless, the code above should fix your issue.